Decidability of whether intersection of two DCFL is empty
Given two DCFL L1,L2 it is decidable if L1=L2.
Now consider the problem L1 intersection L2 = empty language. This is undecidable.
Since DCFL are closed under complement let L3=complement of L2. Then checking if L1 intersection L2 is empty is same as checking if L1=L3(If L1 is equal to L3 then basically it is equal to complement of L2 and in that case its intersection with L2 will be empty).

What is your question?  I don't see a question here.  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require to articulate a specific question.

$L_1 \cap L_2 = \varnothing$
iff
$L_1 \subseteq L_2^c = L_3$. This is not the same  as $L_1=L_3$.

Thanks. I understood my mistake.
